# Were the angels a bit too harsh with the disciples post-Resurrection and post-Ascension?

Tags: angels, resurrection, disciple, ascension

We see in Luke 24 how the angels at the empty tomb of Jesus post-Resurrection, put a point blank question to the confused women disciples:

> Why are you searching for the living among the dead?

Going to Acts 1, we see the angels posing another question to the disciples post-Ascension:

> Galileans, Why are you looking up at the sky? ...

(The salutation itself lacked warmth , because Galilee was not a place regarded with esteem by the Jews . See Acts 2:7) Juxtapose those remarks with the charitable approach that Jesus adopts while dealing with 'doubting Thomas'. One is inclined to conclude that the angels were a bit too harsh with the disciples post-Resurrection and post-Ascension. But, what has been the view taken on the subject by the scholars?

Inputs from any denomination are welcome.

Comment: Could it be as simple as non-human angels lacking human emotions, empathy, etc.? (Those answers wouldn't have been out of place for Spock on *Star Trek* for example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Were the angels a bit too harsh with the disciples post-Resurrection and post-Ascension?**

I do not believe any Christian denomination would think that the Angels were too harsh on the disciples after the Resurrection of Jesus or after his Ascension.

The conversations were simply questioning the disciples. Nothing seems harsh in their speech or demeanor.

They are questioning the disciples in order to clarify what just happened. It is that simple.

Comment: Additional sense: the questions were "didactic", intended to teach.  For example, I can ask: "Isn't that an outdated way to use the computer?" to suggest shifting perspective to another way.

Comment: Thanks, GratefulDisciple. Jesus himself puts a didactic question to his parents after he is 'lost& found ' at the Temple.